# $watch running once instead of twice

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="abc">
            <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
            <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
            <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
            app.controller('abc',
                ['$scope',function($scope) {
                    $scope.name='xyz';
                    var count=-1;
                    $scope.$watch('name',function(nv,ov){
                        console.log('OV',ov);
                        console.log('NV',nv);
                        $scope.name=nv;
                        count++;
                        console.log(count);
                    })
                }]
            )
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here $watch is running only once instead of twice minimum. If I assign `ov` to `$scope.name` `$watch` is running 11 times and in this case the value of name shouldn't change.

Comment: The digest cycle happens twice, but the listening function only gets invoked once because there is no change in value between the first and second digest cycle. [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/7Dc24Ekm4kaBO7Jp8C8G?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, below one is showing proper o/p for me may be you want the same one

```
<script>
    var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('abc',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.name='xyz';
    var count=-1;
    $scope.$watch('name',function(data){
    console.log('data', data);
    $scope.name=data;
    count++;
    console.log(count);
    })
    }])
</script>
```